# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:

Tags: java, hibernate

hi i am new to hibernate. whenever i am trying to retrieve the data from MySQL 5.5 it threw exception 
`Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:`

but when i try to save data in sql table so it is working properly.
Also i found the solution for this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088360/org-hibernate-instantiationexception-no-default-constructor-for-entity-princ) but still it is showing same error.

Comment: Which Entity do you get the Error for? Also, please share the code you're trying to get to run.

Comment: Read the name of the entity that comes right after the partial message you posted, and then read the message, which tells you that this entity lacks a default constructor. So, add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a no argument constructor in your entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private Integer age;

    // A default constructor, one without agruments
    public Employee() {
    }


    // A constructor with agruments
    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

   }
```

Comment: yes added default constructor without arguments but it is showing same error

Comment: Have you checked this in all of your entities?

Comment: hey @geobudex there was a spell mistake now it is working properly thank you