# Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception , GETRequest ,500 error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, http-status-code-500

this is my first time working with spring framwork , and here i was trying to create two table classes and student , with a Many to one relationship , i can insert classes but when i try to get a classe by name , i get a 500 error , this is the error i get ,

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.id,
        c1_0.averagec,
        c1_0.name,
        c1_0.numbers 
    from
        classes c1_0
2023-06-05T09:43:30.727+01:00 ERROR 21428 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity : com.example.student.model.Classes] with root cause

org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity : com.example.student.model.Classes
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard.instantiate(EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4186) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.instantiateEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:663) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:656) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:623) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:527) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.resolveInstances(InitializersList.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:408) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.student.Service.Impl.ClassesServiceImpl.findAll(ClassesServiceImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.student.Controller.ClassesController.findAll(ClassesController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

And this is my entities

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Classes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    public Classes(long id, @NonNull String name, @NonNull Integer numberS, double averageC) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.numberS = numberS;
        this.averageC = averageC;
    }

    @NonNull
    private Integer numberS;
    private double averageC;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classes")
    @Nullable
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

and this student entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String codeM;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Classes classes;
}
```

and this is the controller of classes

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/classes")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ClassesController {

    final ClassesService classesService;

    // create new classes
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody(required = false) Classes classes) throws Exception {
        if(classes == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Classes is null");
        Classes savedClasses = classesService.create(classes);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(classes);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{Name}")
    public Classes findByName(@PathVariable String Name) throws Exception{
        return classesService.findByName(Name);
    }
    @PutMapping("/{Name}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable String Name, @RequestBody Classes classes) throws Exception{
        if(classes == null){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Classes is null");
        }
        Classes savedClasses = classesService.update(classes);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(classes);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Classes> findAll() {
        return classesService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: : principal.Cliente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088360/org-hibernate-instantiationexception-no-default-constructor-for-entity-princ)