# the CommandLineRunner fails to execute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot. I am using a book to practice and I run into this problem. Application run fail. Fial to execute CommandLineRunner.
My CarRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car,Long>{
    
}
```

My car.java

```
package com.example.demo.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Car {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String brand, model, color, registrationNumber;

    private int modelYear, price;

    public Car(String brand, String model, String color, String registrationNumber, int modelYear, int price) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        this.modelYear = modelYear;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    public int getModelYear() {
        return modelYear;
    }

    public void setModelYear(int modelYear) {
        this.modelYear = modelYear;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    
}
```

My DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.demo.domain.Car;
import com.example.demo.domain.CarRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);
    
    private final CarRepository repository;

    public DemoApplication(CarRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        repository.save(new Car("Ford", "Mustang", "Red",
                        "ADF-1121", 2023, 59000));
        repository.save(new Car("Nissan", "Leaf", "White",
                         "SSJ-3002", 2020, 29000));
        repository.save(new Car("Toyota", "Prius", "Silver",
                         "KKO-0212", 2022, 39000));
        
        for(Car car : repository.findAll()){
            logger.info("brand: {}, model: {}",car.getBrand(), car.getModel());
        }   
                         


    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the applicatio.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.h2.console.enabled= true
spring.h2.console.path= /h2-console
```

This is my Error Code

```
023-12-01T17:45:33.504+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 14868 (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\TutoriaL\Spring Boot\Full Stack Development with Spring Boot 3 and React\Chapter 3\demo\demo\target\classes started by ASUS in C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\TutoriaL\Spring Boot\Full Stack Development with Spring Boot 3 and React\Chapter 3\demo\demo)
2023-12-01T17:45:33.515+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-01T17:45:33.688+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-12-01T17:45:33.689+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-12-01T17:45:35.010+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-01T17:45:35.113+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 86 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.       
2023-12-01T17:45:36.261+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2023-12-01T17:45:36.283+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-01T17:45:36.284+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-12-01T17:45:36.396+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-01T17:45:36.399+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2707 ms
2023-12-01T17:45:36.464+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-01T17:45:36.753+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA
2023-12-01T17:45:36.755+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-12-01T17:45:36.772+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2023-12-01T17:45:37.163+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-01T17:45:37.408+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version              
      : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2023-12-01T17:45:37.498+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2023-12-01T17:45:38.006+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-12-01T17:45:39.211+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.example.demo.domain.Car (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2023-12-01T17:45:39.421+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: drop table if exists car cascade 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists car_seq
Hibernate: create sequence car_seq start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create table car (model_year integer not null, price integer not null, id bigint not null, brand varchar(255), color varchar(255), model varchar(255), registration_number varchar(255), primary key (id))
2023-12-01T17:45:39.463+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-01T17:45:40.116+08:00  WARN 14868 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning       
2023-12-01T17:45:40.730+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-12-01T17:45:40.793+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-01T17:45:40.812+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 7.991 seconds (process running for 8.787)
Hibernate: select next value for car_seq
Hibernate: insert into car (brand,color,model,model_year,price,registration_number,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: select next value for car_seq
Hibernate: insert into car (brand,color,model,model_year,price,registration_number,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into car (brand,color,model,model_year,price,registration_number,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.brand,c1_0.color,c1_0.model,c1_0.model_year,c1_0.price,c1_0.registration_number from car c1_0
2023-12-01T17:45:41.244+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-01T17:45:41.278+08:00 ERROR 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication         
      : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity 'com.example.demo.domain.Car'
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy104.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity 'com.example.demo.domain.Car'
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard.instantiate(EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4508) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1475) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.instantiateEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:683) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:676) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:642) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:533) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.resolveInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:397) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.resolveInstances(InitializersList.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:383) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 28 common frames omitted

2023-12-01T17:45:41.336+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Hibernate: drop table if exists car cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists car_seq
2023-12-01T17:45:41.348+08:00  WARN 14868 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-224]
2023-12-01T17:45:41.349+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-12-01T17:45:41.352+08:00  INFO 14868 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I hope someone can sole this problem for me. Thanks

I have try to compare the code in my visual studio code with the book. Its all the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: : principal.Cliente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088360/org-hibernate-instantiationexception-no-default-constructor-for-entity-princ)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

> JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity 'com.example.demo.domain.Car'

You need to define a default constructor for your `Car` class.

Spring uses Hibernate for its JPA implementation, and Hibernate needs to be able to create a `Car` instance by calling its no-arg constructor, but since you didn't write one, it can't create the instance.

The [official documentation for JPA](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#a18) says this about Entity classes:

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected.

Since you don't need to use the default (no-arg) constructor yourself, you should make it protected (use the principle of least privilege):

```
protected Car() {
    // any default initialization if required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look properly this is the error you are getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity 'com.example.demo.domain.Car'
```

JPA documentation tells that you should have a no-arg constructor. It can be public or protected. When you do not define any constructor  compiler will create no-arg constructor by itself. But if you define any constructor then add one without arguments also like this:

```
public Car(){

}
```